# Passing a collection of records to a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to include a partial and pass a collection of records (the moderators of an organization) to this partial. In my organizations controller I have:

```
def show
  @organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @users = @organization.users
  @moderators = User.with_role(:moderator, @organization)
end
```

Show view for organizations (the first partial works but the second doesn't):

```
<%= render @users %>
<%= render 'users/moderator', collection: @moderators %>
```

**The result is an error message: `undefined local variable or method 'moderator' for #<#<Class:0x00000004957488>:0x007f5f51891220>` referring to `<% if moderator.activated? %>` in the partial.**

In the moderator partial I want to only show the activated moderators:

```
<% if moderator.activated? %>
  <td><%= link_to moderator.username, user_path(moderator) %></td>
  <td><%= moderator.fullname %></td>
  <td>
    <%= link_to image_tag("delete.gif", title: "remove as moderator", class: 'profile-icon-small'), 
                data: { user_id: moderator.id, organization_id: @organization.id, method: :post, url: removemoderator_path, confirm: "Are you certain?" } %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your issue here is that that partial is expecting `user` not `moderator`. The local name is inferred from the class name not the instance variable name. [Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) it suggests that you can pass an :as option so maybe something like `<%= render partial: 'users/moderator', collection: @moderators, as: :moderator %>` would work

Comment: Now you are finding a User and an Organization by the same id? And you are calling a method defined on a user without a reciever? maybe try `@user.remove_modrights(@organization)` but I would make sure that this part is really true first `@user = User.friendly.find(params[:id]);
    @organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:id])` because it would seem odd that the user and organization share the same id always.

Comment: Yes, I think I should completely remove the line `@user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])` from the controller method. It is the organization's page we visit, so that's the id available in params. So then it doesn't make sense to search for @user by that id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= render partial: 'users/moderator', collection: @moderators %>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<%= link_to image_tag("delete.gif", title: "remove as moderator", class: 'profile-icon-small'), 
            data: { user_id: user.id, organization_id: @organization.id, method: :delete, url: removemoderator_path, confirm: "Are you certain?" } %>
```

routes.rb

```
delete 'removemoderator/:id'=>  'users#remove_moderator', as: 'removemoderator'
```

Comment: Yes, great, it now renders the page. The `link_to` in the partial however doesn't work. Do you perhaps also see what's wrong there? This line should post to the `removemoderator_path`. I'll add the related route and controller method to the OP.

Comment: I have posted it as a seperate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31123898/4499505.  I tried your suggestion but still clicking the link didn't do anything.