# Link_to with two parameters not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

On a page of an organization I have a partial that shows the users with the moderator role for that organization. Behind each user/moderator there's a link to remove that role. However, this link isn't working. When clicking it, nothing happens. In the url bar of the browser it only shows new text: `https://url/organizations/ek99?data[confirm]=Are+you+certain%3F&data[method]=post&data[organization_id]=100&data[stakeholder_id]=113&data[url]=%2Fremovemoderator%2Fek99`. Does anyone perhaps see what is wrong with this code?

In the **organizations controller**:

```
def show
  @organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @moderators = User.with_role(:moderator, @organization)
end
```

The view page calls on the partial using `<%= render 'users/moderator', collection: @moderators %>`. **The partial** contains for each moderator the link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("delete.gif", title: "remove as moderator", class: 'profile-icon-small'), 
            data: { user_id: moderator.id, organization_id: @organization.id, method: :post, url: removemoderator_path, confirm: "Are you certain?" } %>
```

**Routes**:

```
post 'removemoderator/:id'=>  'users#remove_moderator', as: 'removemoderator'
```

**Users controller method**:

```
def remove_moderator
  @organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:id])
  remove_modrights(@organization)
end
```

**User model method**:

```
def remove_modrights(organization)
  self.remove_role :moderator, organization
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove_moderator 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @organization = Organization.friendly.find(params[:organization_id])
    @user.remove_modrights(@organization)
    redirect_to @organization
end
```

The url in link should contain id.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("delete.gif", title: "remove as moderator", class: 'profile-icon-small'), removemoderator_path(id: moderator.id, organization_id: @organization.id), method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you certain?" } %>
```

Comment: I tried it, but still with the same result: on clicking the link nothing happens.

Comment: You made a parameter mismatch. Try the edited answer.

Comment: Clicking the link now produces an error: `Couldn't find Organization with 'id'=113` referring to the `@organization = ` line in `def remove_moderator`. 113 is the id of the user, not of the organization.

Comment: change `removemoderator_path(moderator.id)` to `removemoderator_path(@organization.id)`

Comment: Now it errors with `undefined method 'remove_modrights' for #<UsersController:0x00000001e85ed0>`. This method is in the User model file and not in the controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81903/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-nick).